# Issue with substr C++

Tags: c++, file, input, substring, substr

I am trying to make a program that reads a line from `tst.txt` using `getline` function. However when I try to get the substrings from it, I get an error that says `method substr could not be resolved`.

My code is the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    string substr(int a, int b);
     string name[15];
     int a[15];
     int b[15];
    ifstream myfile ("tst.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( myfile.good() )
        {
            int i;
            getline (myfile,line);
            a[i]= myfile.substr(4,2);
            name[i]= myfile.substr(18,15);
            b[i]= myfile.substr(36,1);
            i=i+1;
            cout << a[i] <<" "<< b[i] << " "<< name[i] << endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Please help asap" just begs for downvotes..

Comment: When is the homework due?

Comment: `myfile` is a file stream, not a string, so it doesn't have substrings. Did you mean `line.substr()`?

Comment: Also, what is this `string substr(int a, int b);` there?

Comment: + `i` is not initialized, not to say, that it's inside the `while`, which means that the `i=i+1` is meaningless... and some other errors

Comment: + `while ( myfile.good() )` won't work.

Comment: And of course, he doesn't verify that the `getline` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you can't call `substr()` with a `std::ifstream`. What you probably meant was to take the parts from the `line` string read in

```
        a[i]= stoi(line.substr(4,2));
        name[i]= line.substr(18,15);
        b[i]= stoi(line.substr(36,1));
```

Also note you'll need to convert the substrings extracted to a number (instead of assigning them directly), hence I have added the [**`stoi()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

---

As also mentioned in the comments on your question, you should do better error checks, and initialize all of your variables properly.
Your `while()` loop can simply be rewritten as

```
while (getline (myfile,line)) {
    // ...
}
```

The surrounding `if()` block

```
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    // ...
}
```

can be omitted.

Answer (score -1):

You actually prototype a function at line :

```
string substr(int a, int b);
```

But never implement it.

What is the point of this line  anyways ?
Just remove it, you never call this substr function. The only substr function you call is

```
std::ifstream::substr
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: The only `substr` function he calls is `std::ifstream::substr`.  Which doesn't exist, whence his error.

Comment: @johnkork thanks for your reply, well yes that is my mistake I was just trying random things to get out of it. However I removed it and still the same error.